# Mocking render to response with Pyramid

Tags: python, mocking, pyramid, python-unittest, python-decorators

I have a decorator that looks like so:

```
def validate_something(func):
    def validate_s(request):
        if request.property:
            render_to_response('template.jinja', 'error'
        return func(request)
    return validate_something
```

I'm trying to test it like so. I load the local WSGI stack as an app.

```
from webtest import TestApp 
def setUp(self):
     self.app = TestApp(target_app())
     self.config = testing.setUp(request=testing.DummyRequest)   


def test_something(self):
    def test_func(request):
         return 1
    request = testing.DummyRequest()
    resp = validate_something(test_func(request))
    result = resp(request)
```

The error I'm getting is (being generated at the innermost render_to_response):

```
ValueError: no such renderer factory .jinja
```

I understand that I need to mock render_to_response, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to exactly do that. If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library is awesome:

> mock provides a core Mock class removing the need to create a host of
>   stubs throughout your test suite. After performing an action, you can
>   make assertions about which methods / attributes were used and
>   arguments they were called with. You can also specify return values
>   and set needed attributes in the normal way.
>
> Additionally, mock provides a patch() decorator that handles patching
>   module and class level attributes within the scope of a test

Youc code would look like this:

```
def test_something(self):
    test_func = Mock.MagicMock(return_value=1)  # replaced stub function with a mock
    request = testing.DummyRequest()
    # patching a Pyramid method with a mock
    with mock.patch('pyramid.renderers.render_to_response' as r2r:
        resp = validate_something(test_func(request))
        result = resp(request)
        assert r2r.assert_called_with('template.jinja', 'error')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.app = TestApp(target_app())
    self.config = testing.setUp(request=testing.DummyRequest) 
    self.config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
```

By setting up the config to include jinja your tests can then find your template and the jinja environment. You may also need to provide a test version of the template in the same folder as your tests. If you get a message such as TemplateNotFound on running the tests then make sure a version of the template is located in the correct place.