# How to Make view_config decorator work with a Pyramid Unit Test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, web, pyramid, web-frameworks

I wrote a `login_required` decorator for the pyramid web framework. In a pyramid test server it works well.

But in the Pyramid unit tests for the `@view_config` decorator do not work for all configurations (not only the decorator parameter).

This is the code:

```
class MyViews(object):
  @view_config(decorator=login_required(login_url=LOGIN_URL),
               match_param="action=change_password", request_method="GET",
               renderer="accounts/change_password.jinja2")
    def change_password(self):
        form = ChangePwdForm()
        return {'form': form}
```

Here is the test code:

```
def test_change_password_fail(self):
        from .views import AccountsViews
        aviews = AccountsViews(testing.DummyRequest(path='/accounts/forget_password'))
        response = aviews.forget_password()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 307)  #HTTPTemporaryRedirect
```

What i excepted was that the `not-logined-user` will be redirected to login url.
All paramenters in `@view_config` such as `renderer` and 'match_param' do not work.

How can I solve this problem?

References:
[Mocking render to response with Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373013/mocking-render-to-response-with-pyramid)
[Unit and Integration Testing](http://www.kemeneur.com/clients/pylons/docs/pyramid/narr/unittesting.html):Pyramid official guide,but not refer to class-based view's decorator problem

Answer (score 1):

`@view_config()` does not get applied until you run a `config.scan()`.

When you are doing testing, in general you want to test a single unit, in this case the view without worrying about the rest of the framework.

You'd test your view and your decorator separately.

Once you get to the higher level, and want to test that Pyramid is the doing the right thing for your views, you will want to do integration testing. With integration testing you will set up the full configurator object, and the full app, it is more heavy handed, but allows you to test that Pyramid applies the decorator.

The last tests you would want are full end 2 end tests that emulate the full application. The latest documentation is available at: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/testing.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But unfortunately the doc you refers to has nothing about how to test decorators.
I used config.include and afterthat , somethings works(such as `add_directive` , others do not(such as `add_request_method`)).
There is something wrong with pyramid's dummy request object.
I can only added it manualy, for example add `matchdict` and so on.

Comment: Have you tried calling `config.scan('.views')`? I will try and get an example built and see if I can figure out how to test stuff like that. The `webtest` should work though, since it tests your application end to end.

Comment: Yes I did:),scan just add view_config, but settings does not work for dummy request object.Pyramid does not pass any parameter to view callable.URL neither Dispatch do not work nor the view_config.Pyramid's officall document suppose us to use pyramid.request.Request to do that.There isn't any testing example about how to test url dispatch and decoraotr in pyramid's officall github repo.Now i just add request method and property by hand:).Reading source code is too  abstract.I give up because time is limited:)